# Create gradle tasks supporting buildTypes for headless build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, headless

First of all I know there are many similar topics, but I'm confused with this issue.
I have an Android project that is integrated with the `fabric.io` plug-in and `crashlytics` lib.
In our project we're using **Crashlytics** for remote logging and **Crashlytics Beta** for build distribution.
We want to distribute project for two different teams in **Crashlytics Beta** depending on task: one task for Customer builds and one for the Team ones.
We're using [ship.io](http://ship.io) as our CI server but I don't think it is a very important detail.

So, as now I can write in my `release` `buildTypes` something like that:

```
ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "MY_CUSTOM_DISTRIBUTION_GROUP"
```

next I can run my bash script like this:

```
./gradlew clean assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

and after successful building all group members will receive released apk-file.

Is it possible to write custom gradle task which will run sequence of calls

```
clean assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

and apply `buildTypes` which I need?

Comment: Are you using two different release flavors or variants?

Comment: @MikeB As now we try to use `buildTypes` instead of `productFlavors` or `variants`